# Copy of website (only HTML/CSS/Javascript) from Joomla-website

Tags: joomla, browser-cache

I have a simple Joomla-website.
I want to create a copy of my website but it will be composed only from HTML/CSS/Javascript files (no PHP files, database, ...) because I want visit my website without Internet. Only HTML/CSS/Javascript files.
Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks

Comment: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/16423

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, using the same logic as generated cache works, saving the html result pages processed by php.

You can find 2 ways to do it:
Coding: Using an web **scraper** . You can find good Node.js npm packages for it;
Using a 3rd Party software. Google for it.